# login with face recognition

Tags: python, flask, face-recognition

i want to login with my function to use face recognition , i uhave fucntion and i have html login in flask , hen i click to my button login , my terminal is always killed
i use thread in my app flask but always my terminal killed when i use this function in file.py it run correctly but when i want to use in route in flask i got always my terminal killed

```
def run_recognition():

    known_face_encodings, known_face_names = encode_faces()

    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    if not video_capture.isOpened():
        sys.exit('Video source not found...')

    process_current_frame = True

    while True:
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()

        # Only process every other frame of video to save time
        if process_current_frame:
            # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
            small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

            # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
            #rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

            # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(small_frame)
            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(small_frame, face_locations)

            face_names = []
            for face_encoding in face_encodings:
                # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                name = "Unknown"
                confidence = '???'

                # Calculate the shortest distance to face
                face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)

                best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
                if matches[best_match_index]:
                    name = known_face_names[best_match_index]
                    confidence = face_confidence(face_distances[best_match_index])

                face_names.append(f'{name} ({confidence})')

        process_current_frame = not process_current_frame

        # Display the results
        for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
            top *= 4
            right *= 4
            bottom *= 4
            left *= 4

            # Create the frame with the name
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 255), 1)

        # Display the resulting image
        cv2.imshow('Face Recognition', frame)

        # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

    # Release handle to the webcam
    video_capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and this is my login html

```
<p>Use your face to login</p>
   <form action="{{ url_for("logininterface")}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <div class="imgpdf">
    <img  src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/facerec.gif') }}" width="300px" height="300px">
    </div>
   <!-- button upload  -->

   <div class="all">

    <div class="submit">
        <button type="submit" title="Welcome aboard!" onclick="logininterface();">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

i want to fix my problem when i click to button login i ant to run face recognition

Comment: Uhm, your punctation is a little bit ugly. Can you improve it?